# code first para migración con C#, campo tipo fecha

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

Quiero realizar la siguiente consulta, como puedo hacer que un campo tipo Datetime me pueda tener un valor por defecto (gettime) para realizar una respectiva migración a sql server utilizando code first junto a entity framework.
Mi clase de modelo

```
public class ADMMoneda
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOpetion.Identity)]
    public int IdTipoMoneda { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Nommoneda { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int IdEstado { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOpetion.Computed)]
    public DateTime FechaMoneda { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdEstado")]
    public virtual ADMEstados Estados { get; set; }
}
```

Mi archivo de migración con code first no me toma el defaultValue(GetTime()), como lo muestra el código

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.ADMMonedas",
    c => new
        {
            IdTipoMoneda = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
            NomMoneda = c.String(nullable: false),
            IdEstado = c.Int(nullable: false),
            FechaMoneda = c.DateTime(nullable: false)
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.IdTipoMoneda)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.ADMEstados", t => t.IdEstado)
    .Index(t => t.IdEstado);
```

Comment: bienvenido, para realizar preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad,puedes leer [ask]

Comment: Debes quitar las imagenes y poner el codigo (no en imagenes!).  que error te tira el defaultvalue?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usando

```
FechaMoneda = c.DateTime(nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "GETUTCDATE()"),
```

esto cuando definas migrations

[EF6: Adding a Created Date/Time Column Automatically with Code First Migrations](https://andy.mehalick.com/2014/02/06/ef6-adding-a-created-datetime-column-automatically-with-code-first-migrations/)